# How to pivot a table based on the values of one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

let's say I have the below dataframe:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Name', 'Location', 'Phone','Name', 'Location'], 
'Values': ['Mark', 'New York', '656','John', 'Boston']})
```

which looks like this:

```
col1           Values
Name           Mark
Location       New York
Phone          656
Name           John
Location       Boston
```

As you can see I have my wanted columns as rows in col1 and not all values have a Phone number, **is there a way for me to transform this dataframe to look like this:**

```
Name    Location    Phone
Mark    New York    656
John    Boston      NaN
```

I have tried to transpose in Excel, do a Pivot and a Pivot_Table:

```
pivoted = pd.pivot_table(data = dataframe, values='Values', columns='col1')
```

But this comes out incorrectly. any help would be appreciated on this.

NOTES: All new section start with the Name value and end before the Name value of the next person.

Comment: If there is an easier way to do this in Excel Power Query that would be good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new `index` using `cumsum` to identify unique sections then do `pivot` as usual...

```
df['index'] = df['col1'].eq('Name').cumsum()
df.pivot('index', 'col1', 'Values')
```

---

```
col1   Location  Name Phone
index                      
1      New York  Mark   656
2        Boston  John   NaN
```

Comment: thank you for your time. I get a duplicate error cannot reshape error message. I do not believe I have duplicate Names but if I do, is there a way to get around that ?

Comment: I think you have duplicate column names in `col1`..For example there might be multiple locations or multiple phones between two `Names`...Can you check?

Comment: right, I have the text "Name" show up in 'col 1' each time there is a name for a person. and you are correct, there are the same names in column 'Values' - I will try to see if I can drop those and redo this. if I cant drop them then due to importance I will keep looking for ways to pivot